# Angular 7: How to keep the variable value updated in html after changes in ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I have a value that is passed to html when the page loads, but this value is changing as I use other functions and then the variable is no longer updated in html.

I tried using ngModel, but it did not work because I have one object array and one object.

html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itens">            
     <textarea class="textarea" id="item-textarea" [value]="item.text"> 
     </textarea>
</div>
```

Ts

```
public itens:any[] = [];

constructor() {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.initItens();
    this.changeItens();
}

initItens() {
    let item = new Item();
    item.text = "Hello world";
    return itens.push(item);
}

changeItens() {
    let item = new Item();
    item.text = "Bye bye World";
    return itens.push(item);
}
```

I would like to know how I could keep the variable itens and item (item.text) always updated in the html when it was updated in the .ts file

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the case where the value is incorrect in the HTML output? The code given in the question appears to give the correct result. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejnqru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (where `return itens.push(item)` was replaced with `return this.itens.push(item)`).

Comment: `[value]="item.text"` should reflect the value at all times. I suspect the problem is in another part of the code than what you posted here.

Comment: Can you try `this.itens.push(item)` instead of `itens.push(item)`?

Comment: That's it! Doesn't your editor complain about `itens is undefined`? If not, it should. The correct syntax is `this.itens`. You're probably getting an error in the console too.

Comment: no problem with the *ngFor="let item of itens"> , just no update after use the function changeItens

Comment: Yes, and we just told you why :)

Comment: I use this.itens, the variables still not updated

Comment: if I use console.log in the list it is updated, but no changes happen in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are your functions returning the array? It should probably be something like

```
initItens() {
    let item = new Item();
    item.text = "Hello world";
    this.itens.push(item);
}

changeItens() {
    let item = new Item();
    item.text = "Bye bye World";
    this.itens.push(item);
}
```

Comment: Bah, what if they do? I don't think it changes anything. The return value isn't used by anything, that's it.

Comment: Exactly, the itens array doesn't really get changed, so the value doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you reference `this.itens` and when using `*ngFor` its recommended to create a new instance of the array using deconstruction or [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Deconstruction example:

```
 let item = new Item();
 item.text = "Hello world";
 this.itens = [...this.itens, item];
```

Slice() example:

```
 let item = new Item();
 item.text = "Hello world";
 this.itens = this.itens.slice();
 this.itens.push(item);
```

Here's a good tutorial on `ngFor`

https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngfor/